# Access to mobile stereo camera using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, camera, huawei-mobile-services

I have bought this new phone (Huawei P9) which has two cameras at the back and one in the front. I am able to capture one of the back cameras and the front camera just changing the camera ID from 0 (back camera) to 1 (front camera)

```
mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(mCameraId);
mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
```

I have tried other camera indexes (-1, 2...) to capture the other back camera but without any success.

Anyone know how to capture the two back cameras? Or some old example using for example the LG optimus 3D?

Comment: Just for clarification: Is the secondary back camera for depth sensing? Or is it a monochrome camera?

Answer (score 0):

One idea to try is to set the capture mode to monochrome to activate the monochrome camera.