# How to use the stereo camera of Android phone for OpenCV in PC?

Tags: python, android, opencv

*My question is a little different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642209/access-to-mobile-stereo-camera-using-opencv).*

My Android smartphone has a stereo rear camera setup which includes a normal 48MP camera and a 5MP depth sensor.
I am learning OpenCV with Python and for making some real-time applications, I need to use both of those cameras as a webcam for my PC since I want the depth information along with the image.
I have seen many posts and blogs which demonstrates the use of the phone's primary camera and there are many apps available for that purpose, but I haven't ever found anything regarding this setup of streaming stereo camera data from mobile to PC.

Is there currently any way to achieve what I want? If not, can you give me some guidance about how to create such a setup of my own? I don't mind if I need to create the programs myself.

If you need, here are my device information:

- Mobile: Samsung Galaxy M21 with Android 10
- PC running Ubuntu 20.04